# Message selector for Kafka in Citrus test case

Tags: citrus-framework

I was trying out a Citrus testcase where I make an HTTP call whose internal implementation sends a message to Kafka which I am planning to validate with the test case. If I write multiple testcases for this which I run parallely, I want to be able to filter the Kafka message I am planning validate using a header value for which I tried out [message selector](https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/4.0.0/html/index.html#receive-message-selectors) but that seems to work only for JMS. Is there a way I can use similar feature for Kafka.

This is what I tried with Kafka but selector doesn't seem to work:

```
    Map<String, String> selectorMap = new HashMap<>();
    selectorMap.put("ce_traceid", "randomstringg");

    $(receive()
        .endpoint(todoKafkaEndpoint)
        .selector(selectorMap)
        .message()
        .header("ce_source", "eventsourcev1"));
```